# Is the EF mount on the BMPCC 6k weak? If yes, how weak?

Tags: video, video-recording, lenses, action-cam, blackmagic

### BACKGROUND / PROBLEM

Hi, I plan on getting a Blackmagic Pocket Cinema Camera 6k g2 sometime soon, and don't know the physical limits of what the body of it can withstand. I've heard that EF lens mounts are weak, not meant to bear weight, and that the Black Magic Pocket series have the mounts screwed into the plastic, not metal. So I fear it breaking.

I'll have rails and a matte box mounted to them, plus a 135mm telephoto lens that weighs a little under 2 lbs.

Some shots with it will be done from overhead, so the lens is perpendicular with the ground. Lets assume some minor hand shake is applied as if you were doing an earthquake scene.

And although I have no plans to do this, lets assume you whip panned this same setup 135 degrees from any direction as fast as your arms could do it *(bottom to top, left to right, etc).*

### QUESTIONS

Assuming the above...

1. Does anyone know if parts of the camera would break or loosen from these actions?? What are it's physical limits, particularly around the mount??
2. Do you have any suggestions on what would be best for doing these movements safely?? Because the only lens supports I've seen are for when the camera is held horizontally, never overhead. I also know I can use like a GoPro, but let's assume that wasn't possible, because I want to know the limits of this camera.

Thanks!